# Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused. GDBus.error:org.bluez.error.failed:Protocol not available

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, micropython, lego-mindstorms, pybricks-micropython

I'm trying to connect a lego ev3 with micropython to a raspberry pi via bluetooth. Installed bluez and blueman on raspberry. I made the lego address trusted and connected it via the command line using `sudo rfcomm connect hci0 <address>`. The pairing is set for a few seconds, after which it issues`Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused`.
When lego initiates the connection, the same situation occurs, and the display shows`GDBus.error:org.bluez.error.failed:Protocol not available`.

I reinstalled bluez, deleted the connected devices, but it didn't help.

Comment: Your question seems off-topic for Stack Overflow. Over at Ask Ubuntu, however, such a problem has already been [discussed and solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115671/blueman-protocol-not-available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth connect with Lego EV3 available via network connect.
https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/1280#issuecomment-1186266809